# Git: Push local master changes to remote branch

Tags: github, branching-and-merging

I have made some changes in **local/master**. Now instead of pushing them directly to **remote/master**, I want to push them to **remote/new_branch**. So that I may create a **Pull Request** for my lead developer to review the changes and he may decide to make the changes live through **remote/master**.

Any help please ?

Comment: Under the assumption that the name of your remote is `origin`, running `git push master:origin/new_branch` will push your local `master` branch to a branch called `new_branch` living in your `origin` remote repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new local branch

```
local/master to local/new_branch
```

Push that new local branch to the remote server. The new local branch can easily be deleted later if you want. 
Your lead developer will be able to merge the chafes with the remote/master.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Giwan. I did: $ git branch new_branch $ git checkout new_branch $ git push origin new_branch